# backbone fetch collection on infinite scroll

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning backbone and now thinking of how to apply an infinite scroll and fetch/load lets say 20 items from my collection every time the scroll is at the bottom of the page.
I have been searching around a lot after different libs and such without really getting any closer. Anyone that can explain/show how this is best done?

I have now added the infiniscroll.js plugin and trying to get it to work. But on scroll it won't load new items. What am i supposed to do on the appendRender? and how?

```
    var StartView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "section",
    id: "start",
    className: "content",

    events: {

    },
    initialize: function(){
        $(".container").html(this.el);
        console.log("init start");
        this.template = _.template($("#start_template").html(), {} );
        this.collection = new VideoCollection();


        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
        this.infiniScroll = new Backbone.InfiniScroll(this.collection, {
            success: this.appendRender,
            pageSize: this.collection.length,
            scrollOffset: 100
        });
    },

    appendRender: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$el.html(self.template);
        self.$el.find(".videos").append("<div style='margin-bottom:30px; width:100%; height:170px; float:left; background-color:#e4e4e4;'>fff</div>")
    },

    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.$el.html("loading");
        console.log("render start")
    },
    kill: function() {
        console.log("kill start");
        this.remove(); 
    }
});
return StartView;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [backbone-pageable](https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable#infinite-mode) plugin supports infinite scrolling.

It's just a matter of your collection extending `Backbone.PageableCollection`, and you specifying some extra properties. There's also an example of a backbone view listening to the changing collection, as well as fetching on scroll.

It's all described on the github page.  It's updated fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it something like this (although the document.addEventListener('scroll')-part isn't really elegant

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Item,

        url: "/api/items/"
    });

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: "li",

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.model.get("name"));
            return this;
        }

    });

    var ItemsList = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: "ul",

        offset: 0,

        limit: 60,

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new Items();
            this.collection.on("reset", this.addAll, this);
            this.collection.on("add", this.addOne, this);
            this.getItems();
        },

        render: function () {
            return this;
        },

        getItems: function () {
            this.collection.fetch({
                "data": {"offset": this.offset, "limit": this.limit}, 
                "success": _.bind(function(e){
                    this.offset += this.limit;
                }, this)
            });
        },

        addOne: function(item) {
            var view = new ItemView({model: item});
            this.$el.append(view.render().$el);
        },

        addAll: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        }

    });

    var itemsList = new ItemsList();
    $(document.body).append(itemsList.render().$el);

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
        if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) {
            itemsList.getItems();
        }
    });

}());
```

Comment: Thank you! Tis looks good. All tho it goes away a bit from the structure i working on right now. Do you have any idea of how to implement the same thing but in this plugin that im using? When i now scroll to the bottom the plugins seems to get a request for new items but none of them being loaded. https://github.com/joneath/infiniScroll.js

Comment: Also, i don't understand how to fetch new ones once the scroll is at the bottom. The code in my first post almost works.. Its just not loading any new items.